# grep a regex pattern

Tags: regex, grep

I have the following pattern, generated by the a bash cmd,

```
aaaa.efg1.bbb.rt1.cccc.ddd asjdfll
aaaa.dfg1.bbb.jk1.cccc.ddd jkshfjb
aaaa.zxc4.bbb.mn1.cccc.ddd vnncncd
aaaa.ndg3.bbb.bv1.cccc.ddd kjkjifr
```

I want to grep for only pattern that matches

```
aaaa.[a-z0-9].bbb.[a-z0-9].cccc.ddd
```

I finding it hard to generated a regex pattern to match the above.

Please if anybody can help me that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: do you only want to match `aaaa.efg1.bbb.rt1.cccc.ddd` and not `asjdfll` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the first parts of your examples, you have to escape the dots to match them literally and repeat the character classes using a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html):

`aaaa\.[a-z0-9]+\.bbb.[a-z0-9]+\.cccc\.ddd`

For example:

`egrep 'aaaa\.[a-z0-9]+\.bbb.[a-z0-9]+\.cccc\.ddd' inputfile`

To match the last part as well, you could  add a space and `[a-z]` or `\w+` depending on your requirements.